# Storing multiple lines from a file to a variable using a delimiter

Tags: python, filter, delimiter

I am using Python to make a filter to search through thousands of text files for specific queries. These text files consist of several sections, and they do not all have consistent formatting. I want each of these sections to be checked for specific criteria, so in the section of the text file called "DESCRIPTION OF RECORD", I was doing something like this to store the string to a variable:

```
with open(some_file, 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        if "DESCRIPTION OF RECORD" in line:
            record = line
```

Now this works pretty well for most files, but some files have a line break in the the section, so it does not store the whole section to the variable. I was wondering how I could use a delimiter to control how many lines are stored to the variable. I would probably use the title of the next section called "CORRELATION" for the delimiter. Any ideas?

An example structure of the file could look like:

```
CLINICAL HISTORY: Some information.
MEDICATIONS: Other information
INTRODUCTION: Some more information.
DESCRIPTION OF THE RECORD: Some information here....
another line of information
IMPRESSION: More info 
CLINICAL CORRELATION: The last bit of information
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how your file looks?

Comment: No problem, I just did. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, working on an answer:)

Comment: What type of output are you looking after? Are you trying to collect all sections+description (like building a dictionnary?) or do you just want to do some operation once you've found a pair, without storing it? The answers may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use builtin `re` module like that:

```
import re

# I assume you have a list of all possible sections
sections = [
    'CLINICAL HISTORY',
    'MEDICATIONS',
    'INTRODUCTION',
    'DESCRIPTION OF THE RECORD',
    'IMPRESSION',
    'CLINICAL CORRELATION'
]

# Build a regexp that will match any of the section names
exp = '|'.join(sections)

with open(some_file, 'r') as r:
    contents_of_file = r.read()
    infos = list(re.split(exp, contents_of_file)) # infos is a list of what's between the section names
    infos = [info.strip('\n :') for info in infos] # let's get rid of colons and whitespace in our infos
    print(infos) # you don't have to print it :)
```

---

If I use your example text instead of a file, it prints something like that:

```
['', 'Some information.', 'Other information', 'Some more information.', 'Some information here....\nanother line of information', 'More info', 'The last bit of information']
```

---

The first element is empty, but you can get rid of it simply by doing so:

```
infos = infos[1:]
```

---

By the way, if we merge lines in which we deal with infos, into one, it would probably be cleaner, and would surely be more efficient (but maybe a little bit less understandable):

```
infos = [info.strip('\n :') in re.split(exp, contents_of_file)][1:]
```

Comment: First version I posted didn't work due to a typo, I edited it. So if you're having probelms, try using the new one.

Comment: Okay, I will try this out in a bit! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the sections you'll find, here's a version which seems to work, as long as the text is formatted as in your example :

```
import itertools

text = """
CLINICAL HISTORY: Some information.
MEDICATIONS: Other information
INTRODUCTION: Some more information.
DESCRIPTION OF THE RECORD: Some information here....
another line of information
IMPRESSION: More info 
CLINICAL CORRELATION: The last bit of information 
"""

def method_tuple(s):
    # sp holds strings which finish with the section names.
    sp = s.split(":")
    # This line removes spurious "\n" at both end of the strings in sp.
    # It then splits them once at "\n" starting from their end, effectively
    # seperating the sections and the descriptions.
    # It builds a list of strings alternating section names and information.
    fragments = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable( p.strip("\n").rsplit("\n", 1) for p in sp ))
    # You can now build a list of 2-uples.
    pairs = [ (fragments[i*2],fragments[i*2+1]) for i in range(len(fragments)//2)]
    # Or you could build a dict
    # pairs = { fragments[i*2]:fragments[i*2+1] for i in range(len(fragments)//2)}
    return pairs

print(method_tuple(text))
```

The timings compared the regex version of Ilya are roughly equivalent, although building a dictionnary seems to start winning over building a list of tuples or using regexp, on the sample text at 1 billion loops...

Comment: This will work only if there are no colons in sections. (Can we assume that there arent any?) As an example, try changing first line to `CLINICAL HISTORY: Was ill: Yes.`, and keys will switch places with vaues. But if we can, that's a good answer.

Comment: Indeed it is what I meant by "as long as ...". Actually, I wouldn't recommend this if the source text is not trustable, a simple typo (a misplaced colon) can ruin it. Your version is robust because it knows what to search for, which makes it more suitable for untrusted sources.

Comment: I'm sorry for not seeing this when I wrote my comment. By the way, if you use my "optimised" version (1 line instead of 3, and no making list 2 times), is it going to be any faster?

Comment: No problem, you were right for claryfying! I'll give your optimized version a shot, should I post an answer with all versions we've came up with and the timings?

Comment: I think if you measure my optimized version (which would be great), you maybe should just edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found another possible solution for this using the indexes of the line. I first opened the check file, and stored its `f.read()` contents into a variable called `info`. I then did this:

```
with open(check_file, 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        if "DESCRIPTION" in line:
            record_Index = info.index(line)
            record = info[info.index(line):]
            if "IMPRESSION" in record:
                impression_Index = info.index("IMPRESSION")
                record = info[record_Index:impression_Index]
```

This method worked as well, although I don't know how efficient it is memory and speed wise. Instead of using `with open(...)` multiple times, it might be better just to store it all in the variable called `info` and then do everything with that.